# Bootstrap 4 Modal fade effect not working anymore on Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, fade

The fade effect is working fine on Chrome and Edge but not on Firefox.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_nofade&stacked=h

Does anyone know why and is there a hack to fix it?

Tested on Firefox 64.0

Comment: I tried the exact same code here on my local machine whit ff64 and it works. may ure using the cache(http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: works fine in firefox, try again

Comment: @Atomzwieback I have YES to http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ What should I do ? Do I have to delete cache from FF?

Comment: @LondonSmith the site is only a kind of meme it doesn't terminate if ure using cache or not. But please try to disable the cache in the dev console in firefox and reload and see if it works.

Comment: @Atomzwieback It might be something else, I disabled the cache from dev tools and still no fade effect. I also restarted FF. May be a plugin

Comment: @Atomzwieback I restarted FF also in Safe mode but still not working. On the other hand I logged to Windows 10 another account on the same computer and fade effect was working on FF. So it might come from an option!

Comment: @LondonSmith try this "https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings" Reset all settings including dom storage and try aigan.